# How to properly convert my embedded audio and javascript to HTML5 audio?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

At the moment I am using sounds on my website using an old technique with embedded tags and javascript . I want to convert these to HTML5, but I am unsuccessful doing this.

This is the code I have at the moment:

HTML:

```
<div class="au">
    <embed src="audio/tileSelect.wav" autostart="false" width="1" height="1" hidden="true" id="sound1" enablejavascript="true">
    <embed src="audio/tileRemove.wav" autostart="false" width="1" height="1" hidden="true" id="sound2" enablejavascript="true">
</div>
```

JS:

```
//Sounds
function playSound(soundobj) {
    if (document.getElementById('sound').checked) { //if this checkbox is checked, play sounds
        var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
        thissound.Play();
    }
}
```

JS used in other functions to trigger the sounds:

```
playSound('sound1');
playSound('sound2');
```

So all the above works. Now to convert this to HTML5. The HTML part is easy, I think it should look like this:

HTML5:

```
<!--HTML5 audio-->
<audio id="sound1" preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/tileSelect.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
<audio id="sound2" preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/tileRemove.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

But for the JS part I am kinda stuck. Anyone has an idea about this? Tried to change `soundobj` to `soundid`, but had no luck with that.

Many thanks,
Maurice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with the code you have posted.

First one would be the markup that should probably read like this instead:

```
<audio id="sound1" src="audio/tileSelect.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="sound2" src="audio/tileRemove.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

The `<video>`-like source notation that you used is not documented anywhere (although I have to admit that it does not *feel* wrong - but then again I have never used HTML5 audio yet), see **[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)**

---

**EDIT:** Apparently it's ok to use `source` elements inside `audio` elements:

> **Permitted content:** Transparent content, containing either a src
>   attribute or one or more   elements, followed by either flow
>   content or phrasing content , with no  or  elements.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/audio

Still you don't really need it in your case as you just have one source file.

---

Second issue would be that you are using a non-existent method of `.Play()` (capital P), that should be called `.play()`. So your JS should look like:

```
function playSound(soundobj) {
    if (document.getElementById('sound').checked){
        document.getElementById(soundobj).play();
    }
}
playSound('sound2'); //should play 'audio/tileRemove.wav'
```

Comment: Thanks this works, though in Safari, sound1 (a very short sound) is not played, while it does in Chrome. Think this is a Safari issue? Also, if sound2 isn't completed playing, it will not play when the trigger to play it is launched (or VERY soft if I play sound1 right after sound2) If the sound has ended playing, there is no issue. Is there any workaround for that? Perhaps this is due to the .wav format, so I will try this also for .ogg. Thanks again

Comment: @Maurice I think mp3 should be a format that noone has any problems with, but as written my experience reagrding audio is pretty moderate